# Run application from C# code with multiple arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I have following list of arguments that I want to run some application with.

```
 "C:\Release one" "My Manager" 321
```

I see that I should put them to `ProcessStartInfo` `Arguments` property.

But how do I write them correctly because they have spaces in the strings, "`My Manager"`?

Comment: I assume that you tried placing double-quotes around the elements, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"My Manager\" 321";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("something.exe","arg_1"+"  "+"arg_2"+"  "+"arg_3"+"  ");
```

Comment: No, you need to properly build the string as though you were writing arguments in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place them as you show there, in quotes.

So the code might look like

```
Process.Start("myexe.exe","\"My stuff\" "+myarg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
"\"C:\\Release one\""
"\"My Manager\""
321
```

I've not tried this in your particular situation, but it is the standard way to include double quote as a part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the " and the \

Example:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Release one";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"My Manager\" 321";
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this methot to get CorrectaArgumentvalue

```
 public static string GetArgumentValue(string arg)
    {
        if (arg.Contains(" "))
            return string.Format("\"{0}\"", arg);
        return arg;
  }
```

Example:

```
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", GetArgumentValue(@"C:\Release one"), GetArgumentValue("My Manager"), 321);
```